# XPM / UI : Creating new pages based on Page Type with copied components

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, experience-manager

I relatively simple question regarding XPM this time. It's about creating Page Type which editors could use to base their new website page on. When defining a Page Type, you can use an exisiting page to enable this as an example page, including its components. You can copy these components to enable editors to edit these freely without tampering with existing pages using these components as well.
On the SDL Live content docs they explain the following:

> Change the setting from Include this Component Presentation to
>   Include a Component Presentation that contains a copy of this
>   Component. If you use this Component in multiple Component
>   Presentations on this Page, then saving the Page causes all of those
>   Component Presentations to have the setting you configured last for
>   any of those Component Presentations. A number of new controls appear.

This means that whenever an editor clicks 'new page' within XPM, this page type is available and the components that are defined inside it are copied with user-specific prefixes. You can define this inside the page defined as a Page Type itself, by clicking on the component presentations tab, then clicking on a component and selecting Page Type settings. note the following:

[image]

As you can see, the copy of the content is being created in 050 - Web - Global, which is, in our blueprint, the wrong publication. However, in the popup you cannot select the correct content location, only the one where the page type is residing.

I've tested this, also with the UI -specific blueprint context settings, where you *should* define where content and pages are created. However, when creating a new page, the components are copied inside 050 - web - global; the wrong publication. As we're moving to a training, I'd imagine that dynamically created components like this might clog the CMS with content in the wrong location, making it unusable for other publications. Is there a reason for this behaviour, and if so, a way to make this work properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set the BluePrint Context for Components to the Publication where you want them to be created, it should work as you expect.